# Spring boot connect to alibaba e-mapreduce kafka

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka, alibaba-cloud

I'm trying to connect spring boot kafka app to kafka on alibaba cloud.
The cloud is on [e-mapreduce service](https://www.alibabacloud.com/products/emapreduce).
However, I can't connect from boot, maybe due to some security credential that I need to provide?
I've already tried to set the boot properties as follows:

```
spring.kafka.properties.security.protocol=SSL
```

Get error : *Connection to node -1 (/xx.xx.xx.xx:9092) terminated during authentication. This may happen due to any of the following reasons: (1) Authentication failed due to invalid credentials with brokers older than 1.0.0, (2) Firewall blocking Kafka TLS traffic (eg it may only allow HTTPS traffic), (3) Transient network issue.*

```
spring.kafka.properties.security.protocol=SASL_SSL
```

Throws *Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not find a 'KafkaClient' entry in the JAAS configuration. System property 'java.security.auth.login.config' is not set*

Anybody has experience connect to kafka on alibaba cloud?

Answer (score 0):

I believe Kafka Connect could solve your problems of connect spring boot kafka app to kafka on Alibaba cloud:

Step 1: Create Kafka clusters
Create a source Kafka cluster and a target Kafka cluster in E-MapReduce.

Step 2: Create a topic for storing the data to be migrated
Create a topic named connect in the source Kafka cluster.

Step 3: Create a Kafka Connect connector
Use Secure Shell (SSH) to log on to the header node of the source Kafka cluster. 
Optional:Customize Kafka Connect configuration.

Step 4: View the status of the Kafka Connect connector and task node
View the status of the Kafka Connect connector and task node and make sure that they are in normal status.

Follow other steps as your job needs are.

Detail instructions may be find on Use Kafka Connect to migrate data link: https://www.alibabacloud.com/help/doc-detail/127685.htm

Hope this will help you,